# How to use intersect operator in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql

```
(select A from 'TableB' where C = c and G = g)
intersect
(select A from 'TableB' where C = d and G = h)
```

First of all, because Mysql does not provide an intersect operator, I changed the query statement written above as follows.

```
select A
from 'TableB'
    where C = c and G = g and A in(
        select A
        from 'TableB'
        where C = d and G = h)
```

I want to use MongoDB to get the same result as above.

Is there any other way??

Answer (score 1):

```
let mongoQuery = {
    $and:[
      {C: c},
      {D: d},
      {G: g},
      {G: h}
    ]
};

const result = await TableB.find(mongoQuery, {A: 1});
```

This query will return only elements from 'A' that matches `C=c`, `D=d`, `G=h`, `G=g`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. But when I checked now, the question was a little wrong. I'm sorry, but could you check the question again? Thanks again.